# Swift2におけるenumへの変数の受け渡しについて

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift2, xcode7

Swift2で、以下のようにPitchクラスからenumに変数を渡す（enumに引数を与える？）ようにしたいのですが、どのように書けば良いのでしょうか？
もう少し具体的に言うと、View Controllerに置かれたPicker Viewで値が選択される度に、以下のNote.swift内のfrequencyが再計算されるようにしたいと思っています。
以下のコードは実際のコードから一部抜粋したものになります。

```
// Pitch.swift
class Pitch: CustomStringConvertible {
    var reference: Double // 変数referenceをNote.swiftのenumに渡したい
    let note: Note
    let frequency: Double

    private init(note: Note) {
        self.note      = note
        self.frequency = note.frequency
}

// Note.swift
enum Note: CustomStringConvertible {
    case A
    case B

    var frequency: Double {
        // 今まではreferenceの部分が定数だったが変数にしたい
        return reference / 12.0
        // return 442.0 / 12.0
    }    
}
```

Comment: 「変数を渡す（enumに引数を与える？）」と言うのは一体どういうことなのか、もう少し具体的に説明してもらえないでしょうか。Swiftでは実際には動かない/コンパイルできないコードでも構いませんので、実際にやりたいことを(仮想的な)コード例で示すなどして、「enumに変数を渡す（enumに引数を与える？）」というのが本当は何をしたいのかがわかるようにして下さい。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。本文に追記しました。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。まだ少々漠然としている部分もあるのですが、こちらもコードで書いたほうが、そこは違うだとか、それでは要件を満たせないとか言いやすいでしょうから、回答として書かせてもらいます。それではダメと言う部分があればコメント等でお知らせ下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

例えば、static変数を利用してみられたらいかがでしょうか。

```
enum Note: CustomStringConvertible {
    case A
    case B

    static var reference: Double = 440

    var frequency: Double {
        return Note.reference / 12.0
    }

    //...(CustomStringConvertibleに必要な記述等)
}
```

ただし、static変数はアプリごとに1つしか値を保持することができませんから、`Note.reference`を書き換えると、アプリ中の全てのNote型の変数に影響を与えることになってしまいます。
　それではダメと言う場合は、enumではなくstructを使うなり、associated valueの機能を使うなりする必要があるでしょう。`Note`型と`reference`をどう使いたいのか、もう少し上位のレベルでどう使うのかがわからないと、どのやり方が最適かを論じるのは難しいですね。

---

static変数の参照／更新を行う場合は、`型名.変数名`の形で使用します。

```
Note.reference = 442
```

という記述で(`Note`型が参照できる場所からなら)どこからでも更新できます。

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。漠然としており申し訳ありません。
`Note.reference`を書き換えると、アプリ中の全てのNote型の変数に影響を与えるということですが、こちらは問題ありません。
例えば、View ControllerやClassファイルからNote.referenceの値を変更することはどう記述すれば良いのでしょうか？Note型のインスタンスnoteを作成して、note.reference = 442 のように値を変更するという流れでしょうか？

Comment: static変数は、インスタンスではなく型そのものに紐づけられた変数ですので、追記のように型名を直接参照してアクセスします。お試しください。

Comment: 教えていただいた内容で書き換えはうまくできているようなのですが、実際にシミュレータで動きを見るとうまく反映されていないようです。今ある情報で分かればご教授いただきたいのですが、Pitchクラスにて初期化をした後に、Note.referenceを書き換えても反映はされないのでしょうか？

Comment: あなたの`Pitch`クラスと`Node`クラスの`frequency`プロパティの定義だと`Node`の`frequency`の方は計算型プロパティなので、値を参照するたびに最新の`Node.reference`を使って再計算しますが、`Pitch`の`frequency`の方はストア型プロパティなので、最初に値が設定されたら以降は(たとえ`Node.reference`が変更されても)設定されたときの値を保持し続けてそれを返すだけになります。最新の値で毎回再計算して欲しいなら、`Pitch`の`frequency`の方も`var frequency: Double {return node.frequency}`のような形で計算型プロパティにしてしまってはどうですか。

Comment: 無事、反映されるようになりました。ストア型/計算型プロパティの挙動がまだ理解しきれていないのでこれを機に勉強したいと思います。細かいところまで教えていただき大変ありがとうございました。

Comment: とりあえず解決に至ったということで、良かったです。static変数というのは、名前がクラス名に囲まれているというだけで、「グローバル変数の弊害」として指摘されている欠点のほとんどをそのまま持っています。これからアプリ全体を作り上げて行く上で何かしら期待と異なる動作になってくる部分が出るかもしれませんが。その際には改めてご質問ください。